# can't select text in RichTextBox

Tags: .net, wpf, richtextbox, selection

I have a sample of a RichTextBox:

```
<RichTextBox Name="RichTextBox1">
    <RichTextBox.Document>
        <FlowDocument>
            <Paragraph>tveg56ybhj6e7</Paragraph>
            <Paragraph>54 h46u7h 468 j58ik9mm</Paragraph>
            <Paragraph>456 h467h 566ybhj6e7</Paragraph>
        </FlowDocument>
    </RichTextBox.Document>
</RichTextBox>
```

Trying to select all text in RichTextBox:

```
    FlowDocument doc = this.RichTextBox1.Document;
    this.RichTextBox1.Selection.Select(doc.ContentStart, doc.ContentEnd);
```

But nothing seems to be selected. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact it's work, but you don't see the selection because you just lose the focus.
The focus is now on the button

Try adding this line after:

```
this.RichTextBox1.Focus();
```

Comment: And then selecting all is as easy as RichTextBox1.SelectAll();

Answer (score 1):

```
richTextBox.IsInactiveSelectionHighlightEnabled = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

It probably because when you use `FlowDocument` you should check pointer context by using `TextPointer.GetPointerContext()` method.

You can try to use method suggested here: [Select Range of Text in WPF RichTextBox (FlowDocument) Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454440/select-range-of-text-in-wpf-richtextbox-flowdocument-programmatically). The answer is written in VB.NET, however, person asking the question wrote it in question in C#.

If you have any issues when using this solution, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply select all text in rich text box by
    richtextboxName.Select();
and then to place in clip board you can use
    richtextboxName.Copy();
through coding you can get all text in rich text box by using this command

```
string myText = new TextRange(richtextboxName.Document.ContentStart,        richtextboxName.Document.ContentEnd).Text;
```