# How do I jump to a specific line in a RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, richtextbox

I'm looking for an example code how to jump to a specific line of a `RichTextBox` in WPF.

I have no idea how to do this, in winForms it is very simple because I'm free to can set SelectionStart and SelectionLength that unlike in WPF the equivalent properties are read only.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454440/select-range-of-text-in-wpf-richtextbox-flowdocument-programmatically maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have some options in the API:

- [LineDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.linedown.aspx)
- [ScrollToVerticalOffset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.scrolltoverticaloffset.aspx)
- [ScrollToEnd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.scrolltoend.aspx)

Comment: It's true but can we modify the ScrollToEnd and check the offset of line for ScrollToVerticalOffset? i try https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9f4ef400-6479-41c1-afc4-892e1fa398b7/scroll-to-selected-text-in-a-richtextbox?forum=wpf but not work