# Rich Text Box WPF startselection and length

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I have a rich text box in which in WinForms I use the following code in Winforms:

```
private void logRichTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        logRichTextBox.SelectionStart = logRichTextBox.Text.Length;
        logRichTextBox.ScrollToCaret();
    }
```

This works perfectly however I am now reimplementing the user control in WPF and therefore using the Rich Text Box contained in System.Windows.Controls however it does not have any of these features that I can find from MSDN documentation or anywhere online really. Any thoughts on how I can implement the above code for getting the start and length of a rich textbox and scrolling to caret in WPF?

Comment: This looks like your solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13621549/where-is-scrolltocaret-in-a-textbox-in-wpf

Comment: That solution is for a standard textbox not a rich text box.

Comment: I found 2 thing: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9f4ef400-6479-41c1-afc4-892e1fa398b7/scroll-to-selected-text-in-a-richtextbox?forum=wpf and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9013029/how-do-i-jump-to-a-specific-line-in-a-richtextbox
Hope can help

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a richtextbox in wpf like this:

```
<RichTextBox x:Name="richTextBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="296" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="507" TextChanged="RichTextBox_OnTextChanged">
            <FlowDocument>
                <Paragraph>
                    <Run Text="RichTextBox"/>
                </Paragraph>
            </FlowDocument>
        </RichTextBox>
```

You can now hook the even and it will bring the desired behaviour.

```
 private void RichTextBox_OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.richTextBox.CaretPosition = this.richTextBox.Document.ContentEnd;
        }
```

Comment: have to comment that, this solution only help to bring the Caret (pointer) to the end, can't change the view to the end. You need to scroll to it.