# Rich Text Box Select First Character

Tags: c#, wpf

Is there a way in C# to select the first character of the text in a paragraph in a Rich Text Box? I want to do something like this:

```
richTextBox.Selection.Select(0, 1);
```

0 being the start position and 1 being the selection end position.

Comment: check this one out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454440/select-range-of-text-in-wpf-richtextbox-flowdocument-programmatically

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/957441/richtextbox-wpf-does-not-have-string-property-text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the TextRange object to do that. This should return the first character in your richtextbox

```
TextRange justTheFirst = new TextRange(richTextBox.Document.ContentStart,
                                       richTextBox.Document.ContentStart.GetPositionAtOffset(1));
string text = justTheFirst.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
richTextBox.Select(0, 1);
```

Maybe you'll need to set the hideSelection to false before;

```
richTextBox.HideSelection = false;
richTextBox.Select(0, 1);
```