# How to get TextPointers of added words in richTextBox?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, richtextbox

I need get `TextPointer` of start of added word and end of added word in `RichTextBox` in the WPF. Any one can help me? For example I have class Word with property `StartPointer` and `EndPointer` and just Word in string. I read data from file and write to txt. When word is added I want to set `StartPointer` and after added I want get pointer of end of word. Thanks for help.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to StackOverflow! It is difficult to understand your problem. Can you share some of your code and excepted result?

Comment: This are my word property :
`public Word word { get; set; }
public TextPointer StartPointer { get; set; }
public TextPointer EndPointer { get; set; }`

And i read text from file and write it to richTextBox. For example text is hello world. I load first word "hello" and i want get text renage of this added word , StartPointer and EndPointer

Comment: Don't use comments to add to your question. [Edit] the question and put those details in so it is as complete as possible.

Comment: @Kamilex97 Can you look at question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454440/select-range-of-text-in-wpf-richtextbox-flowdocument-programmatically? If that is what you are asking then this can be marked as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

`RichTextBox` has property called `CaretPosition`.
You can get `DocumentEnd` and `DocumentStart` TextPointers from it.

If you have declared `RichTextBox` in xaml then you can access it from code behind:

```
<RichTextBox Name="MyRichTextBox"/>

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var startPointer = MyRichTextBox.CaretPosition.DocumentStart;
    var endPointer = MyRichTextBox.CaretPosition.DocumentEnd;
}
```

Comment: I know that but when i make this :
`var startPointer = MyRichTextBox.CaretPosition.DocumentEnd;
rtb.AppendText("text);
var endPointer = MyRichTextBox.CaretPosition.DocumentEnd;

var textRange = new TextRange(startPointer,endPointer)`
text of textRange is empty always ;/